# Install Qt 5.2.1 and make pkg-config to recognize it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, octave, pkg-config, qt5.2

My OS (Ubuntu 12.04) comes with a pre-packaged Qt4 libraries and other relevant stuffs. But I wanted to use the latest vanilla [Qt 5.2.1](http://qt-project.org/downloads), I have installed it and it's working fine, suppose I have compiled [this framework](https://github.com/kipr/kiss) which depends on Qt.

What I had to do is to add the Qt 5.2.1 libraries to the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. My Qt 5.2.1 home path is `/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64`, and thus my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib` (and `/opt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/QtCreator/lib` for qtcreator related stuffs)

However, recently I am trying to compile the latest gnu [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html). It's `configure` script looks for the Qt `cflags` (i.e. `-l`/`-I`/`-L` flags) by invoking the `pkg-config`.

What I came to know that pkg-config looks for the appropriate `.pc` files to get the exact information related to all compilation/linking flags. My system (Ubuntu) maintains a list of all required `.pc` file locations in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/pkg-config.list`. **But I do not have any `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable on Ubuntu 12.04 (I am not sure why).**

My newly installed Qt5 has a set of `.pc` files in `/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/`.

So, **how do I make pkg-config to recognize the development libraries in the newly installed Qt 5.2.1 ?**

I know that this could be solved by just installing the Qt4 `-dev` packages from the Ubuntu repo, but I do not want to do that. I need the vanilla Qt 5.2.1 for other purposes.

**NOTE:**

- I have added the the path `/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/` to the pkg-config.list but the pkg-config does not update the compilation flags accordingly.
- Adding the path (`/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/`) to `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` does not work as well.

Here is the octave configure script [output](http://pastebin.com/Z9B4hCF3).

Comment: what does the following command returns in your system? `pkg-config --exists --print-errors "QtCore"` ? And does it return when you have  `QtGui` and `QtNetwork` instead? Does any of them cause an error?

Comment: `Package QtCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.`
`Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'QtCore.pc'`
`to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable`
`No package 'QtCore' found` -- same for `QtGui` and `QtNetwork`

Comment: my bad, what I have in my machine are `Qt5Core.pc`, `Qt5Gui.pc` etc. Let me test by adding them to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, and I will let you know.

Comment: did my answer below fixed your problem? Does octave build fine now? Someone upvoted it but I don't know if it was you.

Comment: There is no need to prefix every one of your question titles with a tag - that's precisely what the "tags" field is for. If you want to mention the subject matter in the title, that's fine, but there is no need for a dedicated tag prefix.

Comment: @BoltClock, well, I was just wondering how did you know I am doing that ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is because Octave is searching for `QtCore.pc`, `QtGUI.pc`, and `QtNetwork.pc` but Qt5 seems to have renamed them as `Qt5Core.pc`, `Qt5GUI.pc`, and `Qt5Network.pc`. One solution is to create symlinks for them:

```
cd /opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/
ln -s ./Qt5Core.pc ./QtCore.pc
ln -s ./Qt5GUI.pc ./QtGUI.pc
ln -s ./Qt5Network.pc ./QtNetwork.pc
cd octave_build_dir
export $PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/"
./configure # with fingers crossed
```

I am unsure of the why the reason of name change. I wonder if there should be some sort of mechanism in place where the unversion versions would be in the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, and changing your preferences would change the link to correct version.

Finally, your `config.log` and `config.status` would have been more useful than just the output of configure. The mentioned files will have the actual commands and output of your configure.

Comment: yes, configure works now, at least your hack gives compilation flags. But the bad news is it is giving this `error configure: WARNING: QAbstractItemModel::beginResetModel() not found -- disabling GUI`

Comment: @ramgorur I just checked and Qt 5.2 does have [that method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel). Look into your `config.log` for the exact test that is failing causing configure to say that the method does not exist.

Comment: looks like the current version of octave does not support compilation with Qt5+. 

http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=40252#comment0

Answer (score 3):

The carandraug's answer is correct, but I didn't need to symlink .pc files(Qt 5.9.5). To prevent removing other pkg-config addresses, export `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` like below:

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/`

And to execute it at startup and systemwide(no need to export in every terminal session), put these lines at the bottom line in ".bashrc":

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```